# Windows 7: "Hide file names" for all files?

Tags: windows-7, thumbnails, filenames

So, I just discovered that you can hide the file names of pictures and videos when you are in a thumbnail view in explorer (via View - Hide file names)... but often I have other files mixed in.  This causes the thumbnails to be all spaced out.  How can I hide all file names (maybe folders too)?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 displays the file name when it doesn't know how to handle it or when there is no program connected to it. This is not possible with folders.

look for something like default applications in the control panel (I don't have a Win7 install with me atm).

Hope this helps ; )

EDIT: I think I have the solution:
Try going to "Control Panel->Appearance and Personalization->Folder Options->View" and check "Hide extensions for known file types". I though this was default, but maybe it's not.

Comment: Although I couldn't find .zip and .exe files in Default Programs - Set Associations, .mp3 and .flv files are... and their filenames remain as well.  The flv files even have proper thumbnails.

Comment: Answer updated. If this was what you were looking for please accept the answer and +1

Comment: All that did was hide the extension of the files (which is default, it turned it off), the rest of the name is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Right click, select customize this folder, select pictures, click apply and OK. Now click view and Hide Filenames. The hide filenames only shows up when folder is customized for pictures.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post, but I wanted an answer to this same question and was disappointed there wasn't one here. Here's what I found:

You have to change the "Kind" of the file extension in the registry (Win+R, "regedit.exe"). To do this go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\KindMap` and find the extension you want to hide the filename of (in my case this was .pdf) and change the value to *picture*.

If you haven't already, you also need to change what the folder is optimized for by right-clicking the folder (or empty space when you're exploring the folder's contents) select properties then customize. In the dropdown select "Pictures" (may say something like "videos/images" in other versions of Windows) and press OK. Then, inside the folder right-click>View>Hide File Names.

Sources:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16694/customize-the-five-windows-folder-templates/
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144136(v=vs.85).aspx